# How to save models in pytorch from tpu to cpu

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, tpu

I am training a Neural Network model with pytorch.
Since this model is very complicated, I made use of the pytorch_xla package to use TPU. I finished training the model and now I want to save the weight so I will be able to use them from any envrionment.

I tried to save the data like so

```
file_name = "model_params"
torch.save(model.state_dict(), file_name)
```

and when I tried to load them (from environment which does not support TPU)

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(file name))
```

I got the following error

> NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::empty_strided' with arguments from the 'XLA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'aten::empty_strided' is only available for these backends: [CPU, Meta, BackendSelect, Named, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, UNKNOWN_TENSOR_TYPE_ID, AutogradMLC, AutogradHPU, AutogradNestedTensor, AutogradPrivateUse1, AutogradPrivateUse2, AutogradPrivateUse3, Tracer, Autocast, Batched, VmapMode].

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: what if you try to specify the location, e.g. `torch.load(file_name, location=torch.device("cpu"))`?

Comment: You mean "map_location" and it did not make a difference